# from where the "}" is coming (The current path, entries/}, didn't match any of these.) in Django

Tags: python, django, web-frameworks, django-apps

I have just started learning Django and while making an app in the link it is showing %7D and giving the error :

Using the URLconf defined in ag.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
entries/ [name='list']
[name='home']
^about/$ [name='about']
contact/ [name='contact']
```

The current path, entries/}, didn't match any of these.

I have searched for this over the internet but I have not get the solution yet.

Comment: Probably in the template you have added an extra `}`. Can you show (part of) the template that renders this invalid URL?

Comment: paste your `urls.py` here

Comment: @AstikAnand: `urls.py` is *not* the problem here. It is the template rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template probably contains something like (perhaps with different quotation marks or some extra arguments):

```
{% url 'list' %}}
```

So with an extra closed curly bracket `}`. Since the template render does not see an open bracket, it will simply add the curly bracket. As a result the URL thus will now contain an extra curly bracket.

You thus should rewrite it to:

```
{% url 'list' %}
```

Try searching for `%}}` in your templates.